# How to exit the program if the user leaves a certain checkbox blank

Tags: delphi

So I'm going to be writing an IT test tomorrow and we code using Delphi. My IT teacher hinted that one of the questions would involve us using code that would terminate the program if the user leaves the checkbox blank. Just wondering how I would go about doing this in Delphi.

Comment: How to end a program without the user's interaction is basic knowledge. To see if a checkbox is ticked or not evaluate its `.Checked` property.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [`Application.Terminate()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.Terminate). Or, if you simply close the `MainForm`, the app will terminate itself automatically.

Comment: These are the sound options.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility to terminate the program is the [`halt`](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=Halt&ExpandCode1=Yes) command. But one should use this command very very rarely!

Comment: [Official documentation](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Halt). But in 20+ years of Delphi dev, I have *never once* had to use `Halt` to terminate a program.

Comment: `Halt` is primarily used for serious and unexpected issues. If the user forgets to check a checkbox, that's neither serious nor unexpected.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand sure! ;-)

Answer (score -2):

You may also use FatalExit(0);
This command is available for VCL application.

thanks

Comment: [`FatalExit()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-fatalexit) is a Win32 API function, not a Delphi function. As such, it is also available to FMX apps that target Windows.

Comment: This is a very bad idea. (I mean, even `ExitProcess` would be better! Much better.)